# How can I resize only one dimension in multi-dimension nparray?

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing a NumPy program that would create a multi-dimensional 'string' array (axis 0) consisting of 'strings' (axis 1), where evert string consist of 'characters' (axis 2).

I want the program to be able to dinamically change the amount of dimensions, the amount of strings in given dimension(s), (not every dimension!), the amount of 'characters' in a given string(s) of a given dimension(s) and the value of a given chara.... 
The amounts are being calculated real-time, after what the function `def set_value` is called.

The object (root) is created at the beggining as `np.zeros((1,1,1))`, then is set value of for dimensions, which works just fine but when I get to the part where I get to set the amount of 'strings' in a dimension Value Error is raised. Here's the part of the function in question:

```
    def set_value(value, root, list_of_given_Ds):
        for dimension in list_of_given_Ds:
            root[dimension] = np.resize(root, 
            (root.shape[0],value,root[dimension].shape[1]))
```

Here, the function takes root (that is the object containing all dimensions, see above) and resizes all given dimensions (by doing it manually for every dimension given in the list) to a given amount amount of 'strings' ($value$), keeping the already existing amount of 'chars' in each string (by finding it and using as an argument in `np.resize` function).

What am I doing wrong?

I've made sure that list of Dimensions I am sending to a function consists only of existing dimensions.

Using `root =` instead of `root[dimension] =` does not raise any error but sets amount of stings for every dimension instead for the given one(s) only.

Comment: This would be much easier to understand if you provided a simple example. I honestly don't understand what exactly you wish to achieve, but if you want to make a 2d string array when one dimension consists of the characters, you need to make sure all the strings have the same size (or pad the remainders)

Comment: @Ardweaden the easiest I could: how can I change the amount of columns in a given list of dimensions in a multi-dimensional nparray while not changing dimensions not in the list and also not changing the amount of raws in each column?

Comment: @Ardweaden Say I have 5 dimensions, each of them has 9 columns, each of them has 4 raws. If I want to change the amount of columns in second and third dimension to 5, how would I do it?

Comment: Easiest way would be to append a 5-dimensional array with `np.append`, which has the extra columns in the desired dimension. You can't use `np.reshape`, because the number of "values" in the array doesn't increase using it, it just reshapes say (3,3) into (9,1) (same number of "values").

Comment: @Ardweaden I actually use `np.resize`. As far as I understand, it has the same meaning as using `np.append` and `np.delete` together?

Comment: `Say I have 5 dimensions, each of them has 9 columns, each of them has 4 rows.`, what ? How can 1 dimension have 2 dimensions ? Do you mean that you have a 3 dimensionnal array 9x4x5 ? What is the output of `np.shape(your_original_array)` ?

Comment: You should edit your question to add a minimal example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @obchardon Yes. Sorry, my bad. The output is `(5, 9, 4)`

Comment: `root` starts as 3d with 1 element, a float 0.  `np.resize` makes a new array.  You can't assign that array to an element of `root`.

Comment: @hpaulj but is there any way I could replace some index entry with the array with the same amount of axis?

Comment: Stop trying to change an existing array,  Show us an example  of the array you want to produce. You goal isn't clear,

Comment: @hpaulj That's the whole point. The user determinates the size of array, then some calculations are done over it during run-time. There are two things that are mandatory in this project: 1)User should be able to change the size of the array not only at the beginning but during run-time, aka dinamically; 2)The array should not be only rectangular but also support diiferent length of different axis at different indexes, aka be polygonic. I figured out I could satisfy both conditions if I work with shape of the array directly. For 1st, every time the user changes the size of the array, the ...

Comment: @hpaulj... function is called. For 2nd, this function should be able to work with every index separately in order to be able to assign different length to the same axis of different indexes. The root itself is nparray created at the beggining with the size of 1x1x1, that the user operates with. It all is being used in a roguelike I ma currently writing. Hope I was clear.

Comment: `numpy` arrays have a fixed size, and must be rectangular, not mixed lengths.  You can make new arrays from a given one, with elements copied from the original.  Only `resize` method changes an array's size in-place.  I still don't understand what you are trying to do, but it sounds more like a nest-list operation than a numpy array one.

Comment: @hpaulj Well, I see what I can do. Thank you for your effort!